# Are put/have put...are both grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

- You are put me in an awkward position.
- You have put me in an awkward position.

Do both of these sentences have the same meaning?

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Matt Ellen is correct only in that your option one is not grammatical and your option two is grammatical. The rest of that answer is wrong.

In English, you form perfect tenses by combining the appropriate form of the auxiliary verb “have” and the past participle. You form the passive voice by combining the appropriate form of the auxiliary verb “be” with the past participle.

“Put” is a transitive verb and is peculiar in that there is no difference between its infinitive and its past participle. As a transitive verb, it can be expressed in the passive voice. Verbs in the passive voice do not have direct objects. In

> You are put **me** in an awkward situation

the “me” is a direct object combined with the passive construction “are put,” thus violating the rule that verbs in the passive voice must not have **direct** objects.You can make the sentence grammatical with

> You are put in an awkward situation **by me**

Although that sentence is grammatical, it would not be natural in most contexts. Usually, we would say

> You have been put in an awkward situation by me

Your other sentence with “have put me” is grammatical because there the transitive verb is in the active voice and requires a direct object.

But note that although both

> You have put me in an awkward situation

and

> You have been put in an awkward situation by me

are grammatical, they have entirely different meanings. In the first, I am in the awkward situation. In the second, you are in the awkward situation.

Comment: I was confused by this answer, until I realised that the question has since been edited, so much of this answer is no longer relevant.

Comment: @ColinFine the edit was not made by OP, and whoever edited it seems to have misunderstood the original question.

Comment: @ColinFine Now I am confused. Do I revise my answer to correspond to a plausibly edited question, or do I leave my answer alone to respond to what the original poster asked? I am not sure a third party should make an edit that completely changes the question. New one for me.

Comment: I have no idea. I've raised a flag on it (explaining the issue), but I don't know if that's the best approach or not.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the present participle '*putting*', the verb *to put* doesn't have any other forms - past and future participles are the same as the infinite (I put, I will put).

Context nearly always makes the tense clear, but ambiguity is possible.

For example:

- **You put me** in a difficult position when you **did** that.
- **You put me** in a difficult position when you **do** that.

One clear difference is that "have put" can only be used in the past tense; that is to say, the 'putting' has already been done. This is because, when you use 'have' as an auxiliary verb it can only be the past or present tense, so combined with 'put' it can only be the past.